# Problema con docker y nest: «La autentificación password falló para el usuario»

Tags: typescript, postgresql, docker, nestjs, typeorm

Recién estoy aprendiendo sobre el desarrollo de API´s con nest; en mi proyecto, quiero integrar una base de datos PostgreSQL mediante un contenedor de docker. A continuación el archivo **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:14.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT_EXTERNAL}:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - ws-network
volumes:
  postgres_data:
    external: true
networks:
  ws-network:
```

Estoy sacando los datos de conexión del archivo **.env**. De esta forma

```
POSTGRES_PORT_EXTERNAL=5432
DB_USER=banana
DB_PASS=metabanana
DB_NAME=bananadb

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_SYNC=true
PORT=5000
```

De este modo, no podría haber fallos respecto a las credenciales. Ahora, la conexión está en **database.service.ts**, lo importante del archivo es esto:

```
export const databaseProviders = [
  TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    inject: [ConfigService],
    async useFactory(config: ConfigService) {
      return {
        type: 'postgres' as 'postgres',
        host: config.get(Configuration.DB_HOST),
        username: config.get(Configuration.DB_USER),
        port: parseInt(config.get(Configuration.DB_PORT)),
        database: config.get(Configuration.DB_NAME),
        password: config.get(Configuration.DB_PASS),
        connectTimeoutMS: undefined,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: !!config.get(Configuration.DB_SYNC),
        entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
      } as ConnectionOptions
    }
  }),
];
```

Teniendo este código, correr el programa mediante **npm run start:dev** obtengo el siguiente error:

*error: la autentificaci�n password fall� para el usuario �banana�
at Parser.parseErrorMessage (D:\Diego\Programación\Arquitectura\Proyecto\metadata-cmp\metadata-cmp\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)
at Parser.handlePacket (D:\Diego\Programación\Arquitectura\Proyecto\metadata-cmp\metadata-cmp\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:188:21)*

¿Alguien sabe qué lo podría estar causando y cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Añado que puedo acceder a la base de datos desde el cli de docker, pero nada más.

Por adelantado, mil gracias.

**Eición:** Liberando el puerto 5432 y reiniciando el contenedor, y cambiando la contraseña desde el cli de docker, el error cambia de formato:

*error: password authentication failed for user "banana"
at Parser.parseErrorMessage (D:\Diego\Programación\Arquitectura\Proyecto\metadata-cmp\metadata-cmp\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)*

Comment: El error parece indicar que el usuario banana no tiene el password correcto

Comment: Ya probé cambiando la contraseña desde la linea de comandos de docker, el error persiste pero con un nuevo formato: *error: password authentication failed for user "banana"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (D:\Diego\Programación\Arquitectura\Proyecto\metadata-cmp\metadata-cmp\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)*

Comment: Te ha cambiado al inglés, pero el error es el mismo

Comment: Lo que implica que el problema no es la contraseña del usuario